# How to drag a control to inside the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

Hi I want to drag button/textview or any control to inside linear layout/relative layout . Then if i move control in layout , control cannot move outside from layout . It move only inside the layout?

please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some Listener for your needs, like this -

```
public interface DropListener {

/**
 * Called when an item is to be dropped.
 * @param from - index item started at.
 * @param to - index to place item at.
 */
    void onDrop(int from, int to);
}
```

I've answered one question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383428/drag-and-drop-a-view/8385155#8385155). This may be helpful to you.