# ScaleAnimation Android Api level 8

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a problem:
I have implemented in my project the drag & drop with some icons simulating the drag & drop of android 2.2.
So, when you click for one second an icon, you can start to move your finger and insert your icon in any part of the screen.  The basic behaviour of android 2.2 (API level 8) is that when you do a long click, there is a little Vibration and an Animation of the icon that you have touched and you can start to move.
I have implemented the vibration but i have no idea of what i can implement the little animation.
I have read about a `scaleAnimation` but I'm not sure.
Can anyone explain me the best way to implement this animation?
There are some tutorial or example?
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Comment: I've already answered about [Drag N Drop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8385155/940096) feature. This is not for your related one. But, it may be useful to you.

Comment: this example works for api > 8 and i work with api level 8...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the nice example of drag and drop with animation replacing view [DraggableGridView](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView)

you can inflate your custom layout too and can handle all the events relating with the same.